# custom buttons on UITableViewCell after swipe

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

In my IPhone app I have a UITableView.
I want two buttons to appear on a cell while it's swiped, and I want them to be like the following:

1. the buttons will be my own custom buttons
2. the buttons will appear with a small animation like the normal delete button apple provides.

is there a way I can do it?

thanks

Comment: You need to go through the guidelines. This may cause app rejection because you are violating the standard.

Comment: Can you name the certain point It would violate?

Comment: The way you want two custom button on swipe for a tableview cell.

Comment: how far you have done till now?post code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the boilerplate.com is best to help your problem, it contain different type of cell technique. The swipe with button is also included http://iosboilerplate.com/

Answer (score 0):

I was do in

```
        -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeftRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
[swipeLeftRight setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft )];
[cell addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeftRight];

 -(void)handleGesture : (UIGestureRecognizer *)gec
```

{

```
    if (gec.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)gec.view;
    UIImageView *imgDelete = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width-40, 15, 35, 35)];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *deleteCell = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(deleteC)];
    [imgDelete addGestureRecognizer:deleteCell];
    imgDelete.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"delete.png"];
    imgDelete.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [cell bringSubviewToFront:imgDelete];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^(void){
            [cell addSubview:imgDelete];
}completion:nil];}
```

}